# There are about 28,000 hits for questions with a misspelled "witch"

Tags: discussion

I wowed when I saw it - [site:stackoverflow.com/questions witch](https://google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%20witch). Probably because the spell-checker doesn't help there.

I'm not trying to start a witch-hunt, but maybe we could just mass-replace all the occurrences? I mean the site doesn't have much to do with witchcraft.

Comment: There are lots of common misspellings that could be fixed but IMO this would be a waste of time.  How do you know they might not actually be using "witch" as a reference?

Comment: I said it humorously. I don't really expect it to be fixed. I just wanted to something that goes well with "I'm not trying to start a witch-hunt"

Comment: By posting it to Meta it seems that you expect some sort of outcome. If not, then what's the point of this post?

Comment: It's distinctly possible that there are 28,000 references to the *Holy Grail* witch hunt scene on a programming web site.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: 99% of those will be questions in the Python tag. Only Argument Clinic-style responses to this comment will be honoured.

Comment: @bluefeet Well, I think it's a good idea to fix them, but I don't expect anyone who has the power to do this to ever think it's worth their while.

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to modify English to remove words that are written *almost* the same but have other meaning?

Comment: No they won't @MartijnPieters

Comment: @Bart: *I've told you once*

Comment: @Р̀СТȢѸ́ФХѾЦЧШЩЪЫЬѢѤЮѦѪѨѬѠѺѮѰѲѴ Mark Twain did make a proposal for spelling reform: For example, in Year 1 that useless letter "c" would be dropped to be replased either by "k" or "s", and likewise "x" would no longer be part of the alphabet. The only kase in which "c" would be retained would be the "ch" formation, which will be dealt with later. Year 2 might reform "w" spelling, so that "which" and "one" would take the same konsonant, wile Year 3 might well abolish "y" replasing it with "i" and Iear 4 might fiks the "g/j" anomali wonse and for all. Jenerally, then, the improvement...

Comment: @sashoalm yeah, it would be nice, no more cryptic 'c-words' on SE, they'd have to write 'sword' so that everyone would understand (just an example from one especially vague question) but it's a dream that won't come true.

Comment: Just one another thing: that whole 'widht' and  heigth' issues, 2 words from the same domain with completely other ortographic rules

Comment: @Р̀СТȢѸ́ФХѾЦЧШЩЪЫЬѢѤЮѦѪѨѬѠѺѮѰѲѴ: my biggest beef with the words `width` and `height` is that they are *not the same length* -- it frazzles my anal retentive tendencies. So I use `wide` and `high` instead, and lo, my code lines up nicely vertically.

Answer (score 10):

The [internal search only shows only about 8300 results for "witch"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=witch). The Google search picks up multiple versions of a post (the post, different question lists, etc.), not to mention your search does not exclude Meta Stack Overflow. (In fact, when I use your search string your question here shows as the second result.)

That said, one misspelling like this often points to posts that have other grammar and spelling problems. Fix 'em if you find 'em, but don't flood the front page with minor spelling fixes on old, resolved questions.

Comment: Yeah it was more like "look what I found", I was thinking of posting it on chat, but decided on meta eventually, because maybe something could be done about it. Hope I haven't wasted too much of people's time.